# Multiple Constructors in Prolog

Tags: constructor, prolog, collatz

I was trying to implement various forms of queries on Hailstone Sequence.

Hailstone sequences are sequences of positive integers with the following properties:

- 1 is considered the terminating value for a sequence.
- For any even positive integer i, the value that comes after i in the sequence is i/2.
- For any odd positive integer j > 1, the value that comes after j in the sequence is 3j+1

Queries can be

- **hailSequence**(Seed,Sequence): where the Sequence is the hailstone sequence generated from the given Seed.
- **hailStone**(M,N): where N is the number that follows M in a hailstone sequence. E.g. if M is 5 then N should be 16, if M is 20 then N should be 10, etc.
- **hailStorm**(Seed,Depth,HailTree): where HailTree is the tree of values that could preceed Seed in a sequence of the specified depth.

Example:

```
| ?- hailStorm(1,4,H).  
H = hs(1,hs(2,hs(4,hs(8)))) ?  
yes 

| ?- hailStorm(5,3,H).  
H = hs(5,hs(10,hs(3),hs(20))) ?  
yes
```

[Pictorial Representation](http://goo.gl/0D09Ky)

Now I've implemented the first two predicates:

```
hailSequence(1,[1]) :- !.  
hailSequence(N,[N|S]) :- 0 is N mod 2, N1 is round(N / 2), hailSequence(N1,S).  
hailSequence(N,[N|S]) :- 1 is N mod 2, N1 is (3 * N) + 1, hailSequence(N1, S).  

hailStone(X,Y) :- nonvar(X), 0 is X mod 2, Y is round(X / 2).  
hailStone(X,Y) :- nonvar(X), 1 is X mod 2, Y is (3 * X) + 1.  
hailStone(X,Y) :- nonvar(Y), 1 is Y mod 3, T is round( (Y - 1) / 3), 1 is T mod 2, X is T.
```

For the `hailStorm/2` predicate, I've written the following code, but it is not working as expected:

```
make_hs1(S,hs(S)).  
make_hs2(S,R,hs(S,make_hs1(R,_))).  
make_hs3(S,L,R,hs(S,make_hs1(L,_),make_hs1(R,_))).  

hailStorm(S,1,hs(S)) :- !.  
hailStorm(S,D,H) :- nonvar(S), nonvar(D), 4 is S mod 6, S=\= 4, make_hs3(S,hailStorm(round((S-1)/3),D-1,_X),hailStorm(2*S,D-1,_Y),H).  

hailStorm(S,D,H) :- nonvar(S), nonvar(D), make_hs2(S,hailStorm(2*S,D-1,_X),H).
```

Output:

```
| ?- hailStorm(5,2,H).  
H = hs(5,make_hs1(hailStorm(2*5,2-1,_),_))  
yes
```

which is not the desired output,i.e.,

```
H = hs(5,hs(10)) ?
```

Comment: hailSequence(1,[1]) :- !.  was edited/fixed ? i read hailSequence(1,1) :- !. previoulsy which lead to require this sample  hailSequence(5,[5,16,8,4,2|1]).

Comment: @philippelhardy It was always `hailSequence(1,[1])` in the post, but because it was formatted as a quote instead of code, StackOverflow thought `[1]` meant a footnote reference and rendered it as `1` (note that it is shown as blue and clickable if you look at the previous version).

Comment: @PhilippWendler  thanks for your edit, this help to focus on real problem.

Comment: `0 is N mod 2, N1 is round(N / 2),` will work, but would more appropriately be written, `0 =:= N mod 2, N1 is N // 2` or `N /\ 1 =:= 0, N1 is N // 2`. `X is T` should be written `X = T`. `is/2` is for computing and assigning arithmetic expressions, and `=/2` is used for unification.

Comment: Should there also need to be one more `hailStone` predicate: `hailStone(X, Y) :- nonvar(Y), Y is X * 2.`?

Comment: You are referring to Prolog *predicates* as *functions*, which is not only incorrect terminology, but it is misleading in that Prolog doesn't call functors inside of other functors as if they were functions as in other languages. For example, in `make_hs2(S, hailStorm(2*S, D-1, _X), H).`,  `2*S` will just be the term `*(2,S)` and `hailStorm` will not be called but just be passed as a functor, `hailStorm(2*S, D-1, _X)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues expressed in the problem statement:

- In Prolog, there are *predicates* and *terms* but not *functions*. Thinking of them as *functions* leads one to believe you can write terms such as, `foo(bar(3), X*2))` and expect that Prolog will call `bar(3)` and evaluate `X*2` and then pass these results as the two arguments to `foo`. But what Prolog does is pass these just as terms as you see them (actually, `X*2` internally is the term, `*(X,2)`). And if `bar(3)` were called, it doesn't return a value, but rather either succeeds or fails.
- `is/2` is not a variable assignment operator, but rather an arithmetic expression evaluator. It evaluates the expression in the second argument and *unifies* it with the variable or atom on the left. It succeeds if it can unify and fails otherwise.
- Although expressions such as `0 is N mod 2, N1 is round(N / 2)` will work, you can take more advantage of integer arithmetic in Prolog and write it more appropriately as, `0 =:= N mod 2, N1 is N // 2` where `=:=` is the arithmetic comparison operator. You can also use bit operations: `N /\ 1 =:= 0, N1 is N // 2`.
- You haven't defined a consistent definition for what a hail storm *tree* looks like. For example, sometimes your `hs` term has one argument, and sometimes it has three. This will lead to unification failures if you don't explicitly sort it out in your predicate `hailStorm`.

So your `hailSequence` is otherwise correct, but you don't need the cut. I would refactor it a little as:

```
hail_sequence(1, [1]).
hail_sequence(Seed, [Seed|Seq]) :-
    Seed > 1,
    Seed /\ 1 =:= 0,
    S is Seed // 2,
    hail_sequence(S, Seq).
hail_sequence(Seed, [Seed|Seq]) :-
    Seed > 1,
    Seed /\ 1 =:= 1,
    S is Seed * 3 + 1,
    hail_sequence(S, Seq).
```

Or more compactly, using a Prolog *if-else* pattern:

```
hail_sequence(1, [1]).
hail_sequence(Seed, [Seed|Seq]) :-
    Seed > 1,
    (   Seed /\ 1 =:= 0
    ->  S is Seed // 2
    ;   S is Seed * 3 + 1
    ),
    hail_sequence(S, Seq).
```

Your description for `hailStone` doesn't say it needs to be "bidirectional" but your implementation implies that's what you wanted. As such, it appears incomplete since it's missing the case:

```
hailStone(X, Y) :- nonvar(Y), Y is X * 2.
```

I would refactor this using a little CLPFD since it will give the "bidirectionality" without having to check `var` and `nonvar`. I'm also going to distinguish `hail_stone1` and `hail_stone2` for reasons you'll see later. These represent the two ways in which a hail stone can be generated.

```
hail_stone(S, P) :-
    hail_stone1(S, P) ; hail_stone2(S, P).
hail_stone1(S, P) :-
    S #> 1,
    0 #= S rem 2,
    P #= S // 2.
hail_stone2(S, P) :-
    S #> 1,
    1 #= S rem 2,
    P #= S * 3 + 1.
```

Note that `S` must be constrained to be `> 1` since there is no hail stone after `1`. If you want these using `var` and `nonvar`, I'll leave that as an exercise to convert back. :)

Now to the sequence. First, I would make a clean definition of what a tree looks like. Since it's a binary tree, the common representation would be:

```
hs(N, Left, Right)
```

Where `Left` and `Right` are branchs (sub-trees), which could have the value `nul`, `n`, `nil` or whatever other atom you wish to represent an empty tree. Now we have a consistent, 3-argument term to represent the tree.

Then the predicate can be more easily defined to yield a hail storm:

```
hail_storm(S, 1, hs(S, nil, nil)).  % Depth of 1

hail_storm(S, N, hs(S, HSL, HSR)) :-
    N > 1,
    N1 is N - 1,

    % Left branch will be the first hail stone sequence method
    (   hail_stone1(S1, S)       % there may not be a sequence match
    ->  hail_storm(S1, N1, HSL)
    ;   HSL = nil
    ),

    % Right branch will be the second hail stone sequence method
    (   hail_stone2(S2, S)       % there may not be a sequence match
    ->  hail_storm(S2, N1, HSR)
    ;   HSR = nil
    ).
```

From which we get, for example:

```
| ?- hail_storm(10, 4, Storm).

Storm = hs(10,hs(20,hs(40,hs(80,nil,nil),hs(13,nil,nil)),nil),hs(3,hs(6,hs(12,nil,nil),nil),nil)) ? ;

(1 ms) no
```

---

If you want to use the less symmetrical and, arguably, less canonical definition of binary tree:

```
hs(N)        % leaf node
hs(N, S)     % one sub tree
hs(N, L, R)  % two sub trees
```

Then the `hail_storm/3` predicate becomes slightly more complex  but manageable:

```
hail_storm(S, 1, hs(S)).
hail_storm(S, N, HS) :-
    N > 1,
    N1 is N - 1,
    (   hail_stone1(S1, S)
    ->  hail_storm(S1, N1, HSL),
        (   hail_stone2(S2, S)
        ->  hail_storm(S2, N1, HSR),
            HS = hs(S, HSL, HSR)
        ;   HS = hs(S, HSL)
        )
    ;   (   hail_stone2(S2, S)
        ->  hail_storm(S2, N1, HSR),
            HS = hs(S, HSR)
        ;   HS = hs(S)
        )
    ).
```

From which we get:

```
| ?- hail_storm1(10, 4, Storm).

Storm = hs(10,hs(20,hs(40,hs(80),hs(13))),hs(3,hs(6,hs(12)))) ? ;

no
```

Comment: hail_storm with seed = 4 should not have any left subtree (i.e. 1), as shown in the pictorial representation in the question.

Comment: 1 more thing..if I want to convert the returned hailstorm into a list, like 
     | ?- hail_storm (1 ,3 ,storm), hail_list(storm ,list).  
     storm = hs(1,hs(2,hs(4)))
     list = [1,[2,[4]]] ?  
     yes

Comment: @sarvagya yes you are correct. I fixed the issue which was that a constraint is needed in `hail_stone` which forces `S` to be greater than `1`.

Comment: How you render it as a list is up to you. It could look like, `[N,L,R]` for two branches (`L` and `R` being subtrees), `[N,S]` (`S` being the only subtree)`, or `[N]` (a node value with no subtree). You can easily modify the answer I provided to yield a list instead of `hs` notation if you study it a bit. Note also that variables MUST start upper case: `hail(Storm, Llist)`, not `hail(storm, list)`.